# I don't get this joke

Tags: jokes

Isaw it on instagram and I don't get the joke or pun, it said,

> me and my plant gf
>   me: “bby your hands is so thin”
>   her: “that me leaf”

Comment: I wouldn't blame myself for not understanding it—especially if there is no photograph to go with it. My guess is that the picture includes a person and a plant and that the joke works along the lines of "I broke up with my plant girlfriend. She was too much into pot, so I told her I was leafing."

Comment: Can you give the link to the instagram page where you found this?

Answer (score 4):

Original version (unedited):

> "me and my plant gf me - bby your hands is so thin her - that me leaf"

My version is:

> **Me and My Plant Girlfriend**
>
> ME:   Baby, your hand is so thin!
>
> HER:  That's my leaf!

Which is a poor joke, really. Isn't it? But having had to work it out (if this is really what it means) has made me smile a little.

Comment: +1. Definitely the right translation, Margana. I couldn't figure out what the "me" and the "her" before the two hyphens were doing (because there is no punctuation before those words to set them off from the preceding words in each case). But your reading makes perfect sense.

Comment: @Sven: your (incorrect) translation is much funnier.

Comment: @PeterShor: "Your (incorrect) translation [Sven] is much funnier". True indeed.

Comment: @SvenYargs There was actually, but since SE strips out single line breaks, it ended up looking like complete nonsense. I've edited the question to look like how it was typed out. I still don't get the joke either, by the way.